# How to setup IIS to use it for our intranet site?

Tags: iis, configuration

I am new to IIS and have a Windows 2008 R2 web server called MYWEBSERVER. I have a new website called `foo`. I want to deploy to it and I want to know how I can deploy it so that it can be accessed like `http://foo.mywebserver` or like `http://mywebserver/foo` .

I have physically placed my website in the D:/sites/foo folder on the server. This is an intranet site that will only be accessed locally on a network. It will not be accessible from the internet.

It works fine in Visual Studio, and I've copied it to the webserver, but now what do I do?

Comment: Did you try to access the website? What did you get?

Comment: No because I haven't set it up. That's my question - how do I set it up? It works fine in Visual Studio, and I've copied it to the webserver, but now what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd go with the `http://mywebserver/foo` option, so you don't have to add a host name to your domain server's DNS settings.

Then, in Internet Information Server Manager, go to "Sites" / "Default Web Site", right click "Add Application..." and insert "foo" as name and specify the folder on the server where you want to put your application files (aspx, html, images, bin etc.). In your case that would be

```
D:/sites/foo
```

(You could also copy the files in a subfolder of Inetpub\wwwroot, which is the Default Web Site's root folder.)

Don't forget to check the .NET framework version option and other configuration settings (default document, logging, access, ...).